# Stop scrapy from redirecting to country specific domain

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from airbnb.com. But whenever I tried to access that website with .com in its domain, it's redirecting to a domain having .ca.

Here is a code snippet which I think would describe my issue

```
In [46]: fetch(url)                      
2021-02-05 09:17:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.airbnb.ca/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2> from <GET https://www.airbnb.com/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths[]=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query>
                                                                                    

2021-02-05 09:17:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.airbnb.ca/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2> (referer: None)
```

Actually, airbnb loads prices for each listing with the domain having .com. I tried various solution like don_redirect etc. but haven't received required response.

Comment: If you can get this to work as expected in a web browser, then https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#reproducing-requests