# Airbnb redirecting in scrapy request

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, scrapy, http-headers

I previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064965/stop-scrapy-from-redirecting-to-country-specific-domain) about what's the possible way of stopping scrapy request from being redirecting to a country specific domain. I am still trying to find a solution.

This is an [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2) link having .com in its domain and with this domain, prices are also loaded for each listing. But whenever I tried to get response from that url(having .com in domain), scrapy is redirecting to country specific domain like [this](https://www.airbnb.ca/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2)

```
In [1]: co = 'OptanonAlertBoxClosed=NR; bev=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2; cdn_exp_75142abeb19c4bc33=treatment; cdn_exp_194_exposure_group=93; tzo=0; sdid=; jitney_cl
   ...: ient_session_id=c00c390d-bbca-4ff3-8d20-626e336eb80b; jitney_client_session_created_at=1612599695; _user_attributes=%7B%22curr%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22guest_exc
   ...: hange%22%3A1.0%2C%22device_profiling_session_id%22%3A%221612524047--c7cbbf7b2f5f3951cc233ac6%22%2C%22giftcard_profiling_session_id%22%3A%221612599693--871f5
   ...: 911c19c81328f051a4e%22%2C%22reservation_profiling_session_id%22%3A%221612599693--369e992f8ad75f838d7cad90%22%7D; frmfctr=wide; cfrmfctr=DESKTOP; cbkp=3; __s
   ...: sid=c7fa024d87706361f0a1c355ae86202; _uetsid=34c9580067a411ebb0c3add6fa87bf0c; _uetvid=34c9743067a411ebbddd17c9b2ba0906; _gcl_au=1.1.589303471.1612524081; _
   ...: ga=GA1.2.1698629363.1612529194; _gid=GA1.2.1762113421.1612529194; country=PK; previousTab=%7B%22id%22%3A%22b752858b-4eab-48f8-82e4-43e22b748955%22%2C%22url%
   ...: 22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.airbnb.com%2Fs%2Fnova%2Fhomes%3Ftab_id%3Dhome_tab%26refinement_paths%5B%5D%3D%252Fhomes%26date_picker_type%3Dcalendar%26source%3Ds
   ...: tructured_search_input_header%26search_type%3Dsearch_query%26locale%3Den%26_set_bev_on_new_domain%3D1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2%22%7D; _csrf_token=V4%24.air
   ...: bnb.com%24qoNEhDsTs_8%24BJ6PFRt0hqmlaF9sHAnjGkkACn6mL9-Miw7vmr-kj6U%3D; flags=0; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=NR; jitney_client_session_updated_at=1612601267; stic
   ...: ky_locale=en; ak_bmsc=63C67A1DD842CC3308F97934DB0780C56846EBADA95A00008E511E60DEF9060C~pl3lqKCz8kOjp4Gm5txm/4bYemOuuaMgC/ALCSFezFeStKenBxOTYHHMwk5g0YvxYoGWu
   ...: OWa7w1ugOPUXloKWnWvSQZJzYgSuDBVvx+5sLa8p1ojzp5vzlYasJotx9ViM7zSD5sGSHO1v+M/+CR5/n6mGD4DZxUDOTZGvQdgxX+YSHAx8mQgEoTdulq/DLS8TsaBOdNcWb7FEBdelBfVXJyrbZ52NtcBw
   ...: nP6OnQRkvhxA=; bm_sv=48F03C34885B5025FB7B340B6F5D58C8~PYCRXFbB4XBnDtNvfjGr+ofDVAlx3ohtfXcCqkmQj6vCdGrYi+k1YtIqUXmYjoEU0w10/gmry27JnrjcqYA4Yzmo3FWPeQxJxbIBDT
   ...: 5Ny1JPUpaCyJiHDy2XC8AxjQTpDCdIN4WPUF5Lcmvw0tjseua6z4zT2FeWdtV8kX9qt40=; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; _gat=1'

In [2]: url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths[]=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&searc
   ...: h_type=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2'

In [3]: scrapy.Request(url,headers={'Cookies':co})
Out[3]: <GET https://www.airbnb.com/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths[]=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_t
ype=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2>

In [4]: fetch(scrapy.Request(url,headers={'Cookies':co}))
-- INFO  [21-02-06 03:51:26] scrapy.core.engine.open_spider:272
Spider opened
-- INFO  [21-02-06 03:51:26] default.spider_opened:103
Spider opened: default
-- WARNING [21-02-06 03:51:26] py.warnings._showwarnmsg:109
c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\contextfactory.py:49: DeprecationWarning: Passing method to twisted.internet.ssl.CertificateOption
s was deprecated in Twisted 17.1.0. Please use a combination of insecurelyLowerMinimumTo, raiseMinimumTo, and lowerMaximumSecurityTo instead, as Twisted will correct
ly configure the method.
  return CertificateOptions(

-- DEBUG [21-02-06 03:51:27] scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect._redirect:40
Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.airbnb.ca/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519
553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&locale=en> from <GET https://www.airbnb.com/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refineme
nt_paths[]=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4
NzI2>
-- DEBUG [21-02-06 03:51:31] scrapy.core.engine._on_success:250
Crawled (200) <GET https://www.airbnb.ca/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk
3ZTMyZGU4NzI2&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=search_query&locale=en> (referer: None)

In [5]: fetch(scrapy.Request(url,headers={'Cookies':co},meta={'dont_redirect':True}))
-- WARNING [21-02-06 03:52:08] py.warnings._showwarnmsg:109
c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\contextfactory.py:49: DeprecationWarning: Passing method to twisted.internet.ssl.CertificateOption
s was deprecated in Twisted 17.1.0. Please use a combination of insecurelyLowerMinimumTo, raiseMinimumTo, and lowerMaximumSecurityTo instead, as Twisted will correct
ly configure the method.
  return CertificateOptions(

-- DEBUG [21-02-06 03:52:08] scrapy.core.engine._on_success:250
Crawled (307) <GET https://www.airbnb.com/s/nova/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths[]=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&se
arch_type=search_query&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1612519553_NTk3ZTMyZGU4NzI2> (referer: None)

In [6]: view(response)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c68f42c3ba27> in <module>
----> 1 view(response)

c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\response.py in open_in_browser(response, _openfunc)
     67     from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse, TextResponse
     68     # XXX: this implementation is a bit dirty and could be improved
---> 69     body = response.body
     70     if isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
     71         if b'<base' not in body:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'body'
```

Tried to send cookies for different region with `dont_redirect: True` but haven't received required response. Any trick to resolve redirection problem.

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66064965/939364 ? Please, remove one of them.